# PostgreSQL fsync off for a single database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a write-intensive database stored in PostgreSQL v9.4.4 and it causes IO on my device. I'd like to switch `fsync` off for only a single database, not PostgreSQL server wide. (I accept that it can cause corruption when unexpected shutdown occurs). Help me find out how to make it.

Comment: No, that's not possible. The fsync setting is always for the complete cluster (instance)

Comment: You can keep two PostgreSQL clusters on the same machine - move that DB to a separate one and you can configure it as you wish.

Comment: You may want to play with [checkpoints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-CHECKPOINTS)

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check unlogged tables, they do not produce WALs at all. But of course if crash happen - all data from them will be lost and they cannot be replicated.

Also there is much safer setting `synchronous_commit` which could reduce IO and it's possible to set it per session or per user/database.

Comment: Which in this case, would look like `alter database that_database set synchronous_commit TO off;`.  It will not take effect in existing connections, only ones started after the change is made.